# Probability : A phone number has seven digits and cannot begin with a 0. How many phone numbers contain the sequence 123.

Tags: combinatorics

I have seen this question in edx and the solution the instructor has given is very specific where she manually count each exceptions. Is there any other standard method which can be used ?

Answer (score 3):

Approach with inclusion-exclusion on the events "The first through the third digits are 1,2,3 respectively", "The second through the fourth digits are 1,2,3 respectively", ... "The fifth through the seventh digits are 1,2,3 respectively."  I will refer to these events as $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_5$ respectively.

We are tasked with calculating $|A_1\cup A_2\cup\dots\cup A_5|$, i.e. our phone number contains the subsequence $1,2,3$.

It should be clear that $|A_1| = 10^4$ and that $|A_n| = 9\cdot 10^3$ for each $n\geq 2$

Further, it should be clear that $A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset$ in every event where $i<j$ except for $A_1\cap A_4, A_1\cap A_5$ and $A_2\cap A_5$ which have cardinalities $10,10,9$ respectively.  Finally, it should be clear that $A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k = \emptyset$ for all $i<j<k$.

We get then a final total count as being:

$$10^4+4\cdot 9\cdot 10^3 - 10 - 10 - 9 = 45971$$

Comment: Neat solution. I’d be interested in what the OP’s given solution was though.. because I feel like this method still contains some ‘manual counting’ of exceptions (not that I think it can be made much better!).